# Why does setiosflags in C++ appear not to set the specified flag?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x = 44;
    cout << setiosflags(ios::oct) << x;
}
```

Why am I getting the output as (decimal) 44 rather than (octal) 54? How can I change this?

Comment: If you see e.g. [this `setiosflags` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setiosflags) you will see that the example calls [`resetiosflags`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/resetiosflags) first. Have you tried that?

Comment: Since you are setting only one flag, you should use [`std::oct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) instead: `cout << oct << x;`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude I have referred to the link mentioned but why that works after resetting ?

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/resetiosflags), you should clear all format flags first

> When used in an expression out << resetiosflags(mask) or in >>
>   resetiosflags(mask), clears all format flags of the stream out or in
>   as specified by the mask.

write something like this;

```
cout << std::resetiosflags(std::ios_base::dec) << setiosflags(ios_base::oct) << x;
```

Comment: What if it was formerly hex?

Comment: You can use std::ios_base::basefield then

Comment: Yep! cpp io library is bullsiht. printf is much much much much much much ... easier to use. And I swear to god I never realized any performance problems. Cpp really tries hard to be an impossible language.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only setting a single flag, [use the `std::oct` manipulator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) directly, rather than setting the `std::ios_base::oct` flag:

```
std::cout << std::oct << x;
```

When using `setiosflags`, you also need to use `resetiosflags` to clear already set flags.